# Why is my display element not responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like my header to change with the page size, so I used bootstrap display, but it is not responsive. I am working in Vue JS 3.

The element:

```css
.header-title {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="header-title display-4">Title</h1>
```

The styles displayed in the console no matter the screen size.

```css
.header-title {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
}

.display-4 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class="header-title display-4">Title</h1>
```

Comment: You're using `rem` as a size unit for the headline. This value relies on the font-size set on the root element `<html>`, if the font-size on this element never changes, `3.5rem` will always stay the same.

Comment: @makkusu thank you for the comment! How would this be fixed? by changing the size unit? Also, since this is the default for bootstrap display shouldn't this value be responsive anyways?

Comment: If you want to change the size of the rem, you could either change the rem size on the `.display-4` itself by using media-queries or you could do it the same way with media-queries but on the actual `<html>`-root element. If you would like to always scale text based on the viewport width, you can try out the unit `vw`, which stands for the same, so `5vw` would be equal to 5% of the whole viewport width.
Not sure which version of bootstrap you're using but I checked the docs and display-4 has the following font-size `calc(1.475rem+2.7vw)`, so it is already using viewport width.Maybe update BS.

Comment: @makkusu That's what I'm so confused about, it should be scaling and I know for a fact that it is not overwritten anywhere. my bootstrap is currently up to date. I might just switch to vw like you said, but I still wonder why the default class doesn't work.

Comment: I just added Bootstrap 5.3.3 in a codepen and added the same HTML as from your post. Resizing the windows lets the heading shrink and grow as expected.